# What to extract a value from object

Tags: python, json

I want the media field from my tweets json but I am unable to get it instead I am getting some unnecessary data.
here is the code I am Using:

```
import csv
with open('csvdatafile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fin, open('textdata.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=' ')
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        writer.writerow(row[23]);
```

and I get

```
e x t e n d e d _ e n t i t i e s
{ ' m e d i a ' : " " [ { ' i d ' : " " 1 4 7 5 6 9 7 6 9 1 5 3 9 7 8 3 6 8 8 , " " ' i d _ s t r ' : " " ' 1 4 7 5 6 9 7 6 9 1 5 3 9 7 8 3 6 8 8 ' , " " ' i n d i c e s ' : " " [ 8 6 , " " 1 0 9 ] , " " ' m e d i a _ u r l ' : " " ' h t t p : / / p b s . t w i m g . c o m / m e d i a / F H q 7 O 1 w X w A g D 4 F g . j p g ' , " " ' m e d i a _ u r l _ h t t p s ' : " " ' h t t p s : / / p b s . t w i m g . c o m / m e d i a / F H q 7 O 1 w X w A g D 4 F g . j p g ' , " " ' u r l ' : " " ' h t t p s : / / t . c o / Y g o U X d R f 6 q ' , " " ' d i s p l a y _ u r l ' : " " ' p i c . t w i t t e r . c o m / Y g o U X d R f 6 q ' , " " ' e x p a n d e d _ u r l ' : " " ' h t t p s : / / t w i t t e r . c o m / K a t a n a H u g o / s t a t u s / 1 4 7 5 6 9 7 7 0 9 0 0 0 6 2 6 1 7 6 / p h o t o / 1 ' , " " ' t y p e ' : " " ' p h o t o ' , " " ' s i z e s ' : " " { ' t h u m b ' : " " { ' w ' : " " 1 5 0 , " " ' h ' : " " 1 5 0 , " " ' r e s i z e ' : " " ' c r o p ' } , " " ' l a r g e ' : " " { ' w ' : " " 7 2 0 , " " ' h ' : " " 8 9 9 , " " ' r e s i z e ' : " " ' f i t ' } , " " ' m e d i u m ' : " " { ' w ' : " " 7 2 0 , " " ' h ' : " " 8 9 9 , " " ' r e s i z e ' : " " ' f i t ' } , " " ' s m a l l ' : " " { ' w ' : " " 5 4 5 , " " ' h ' : " " 6 8 0 , " " ' r e s i z e ' : " " ' f i t ' } } , " " ' s o u r c e _ s t a t u s _ i d ' : " " 1 4 7 5 6 9 7 7 0 9 0 0 0 6 2 6 1 7 6 , " " ' s o u r c e _ s t a t u s _ i d _ s t r ' : " " ' 1 4 7 5 6 9 7 7 0 9 0 0 0 6 2 6 1 7 6 ' , " " ' s o u r c e _ u s e r _ i d ' : " " 7 1 8 8 6 3 3 2 8 0 6 0 2 8 9 0 2 5 , " " ' s o u r c e _ u s e r _ i d _ s t r ' : " " ' 7 1 8 8 6 3 3 2 8 0 6 0 2 8 9 0 2 5 ' } ] }
```

but I only want the media_url

Comment: Welcome to SO.! Nice to see you found your way here! You need to provide samples of your data. It is otherwise hard to troubleshoot you problem. When providing the samples, do not post images. Instead, paste the data in the question, the same way you posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Maybe this can help you.

```py
import csv
    
with open('csvdatafile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fin, open('textdata.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fout:
   reader = csv.reader(fin)
   next(reader)
   output = []
   for row in reader:
      output.append(row[:])
      writeURL = (str(output[0][4]).split("\'media_url\':\"\"\'"))[1].replace('\'','')
      fout.write(writeURL)
```

Comment: it shows list index out of range what should I do?

Comment: Can you share the content of 'csvdatafile.csv' file?